# django make a request based on the data received

Tags: django-queryset

opening a task by uuid

```
  {
        "id": 4,
        "userInfo": 1,
        "uuid": "5a722487",
        "title": "Comparing numbers"
    }
```

how to save the id and userinfo to pass to another request without specifying in the url /<'userInfo'>/<'id'> and get recommendations for the received task

```
[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "userInfo": 1,
        "uuid": "1e6a7182",
        "title": "The opposite number"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "userInfo": 1,
        "uuid": "9de9f5d0",
        "title": "Your order, please"
    },
]
```

Comment: can you explain your need more ?

Comment: changed the question a bit

Answer (score 0):

Concider using custom serializer for you objects